# My icon for photo is missing not only from dock but from launch pad on my MacBooks Air

Tags: icon

I have tried the rebuild but when I relaunch launchpad still does not show the photo icon. How do I get it back on my MacBook Air

Comment: Are you referring to the photos.app or something else?

Comment: You can press command-space, enter photos.app to open it and then right-click the icon in the Dock and pin it to have it permanently in the Dock again.

Answer (score 1):

The quick way to find any app you might be able to delete is open the App Store app and find the app using search.

- if the app is deleted, you can reinstall it
- if the app is just moved, you can open it

Once it’s open, keep it in the dock with a control click or right click. Spotlight can help you find the app in finder if you need to put it back in the Applications folder